# How to pass WebAssembly.Memory object to WASM module that is instantiated from the glue .js file?

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I found lots of tutorials for passing env to modules that are compiled from the .wasm file. how is it possible to do it from the compilation output .js file (with MODULARIZE=1)?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem. Would you clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a WASM module that I use successfully from JS (FFTW..),
when I move it to a WebWorker the behavior is strange. calling malloc and creating a typed array from the buffer. typedarray.set() call result in a very strange array (only 2 elements and the reset are zeros). it happens only in a WebWorker so I wanted to try to initialize my own memory object for testing it..

Comment: I initialize the module from the .js file and not by fetching and compiling the .wasm file (which I can see examples for how to pass a memory object in the env)

Comment: Have you tried to use the [total_memory](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L57) compile option?

Comment: no. any chance it'll solve the webworker issue?

Comment: I've added an answer to better explain the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to specify the Memory object while keeping the glue. However, looking at the glue we have:

```
Module['wasmMemory'] = new WebAssembly.Memory({ 'initial': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE, 'maximum': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE });
```

You can provide compile option `TOTAL_MEMORY` to change how the object is initialized

```
-s TOTAL_MEMORY=<val>
```

The default value is 16777216 and it is divided by 65536 (`WASM_PAGE_SIZE`) leaving us with a default of 256 pages.